acylindrically hyperbolic groups have hyperbolic Cayley graphs?
I am trying to make sense of Theorem 2.14 in Osin's article:
https://eta.impa.br/dl/071.pdf
It lists three equivalent conditions for a group $G$ to be acylindrically hyperbolic. Condition (c) reads:

(c) There exists a generating set $X$ of $G$ such that the corresponding Cayley graph
$\Gamma(G; X)$ is hyperbolic, $|\partial\Gamma(G; X)| > 2$, and the natural action of $G$ on $\Gamma(G; X)$ is acylindrical.

But it is known that a finitely generated group has hyperbolic Cayley graph if and only if $G$ is hyperbolic itself (it is cited in the same article on p. 940). So condition (c) makes acylindrically hyperbolic groups a subclass of hyperbolic groups, which is clearly incorrect. Where is the mistake?

What makes you think $X$ is finite here?

@MoisheKohan looks like this is the reason for my confusion, I assumed that $X$ is finite. Thanks!

It turned out that $X$ is not supposed to be finite in the cited condition (c). Thanks for Moishe Kohan for the hint. I found explicit mention of it in Clara Loeh' book on p. 277:

A group $G$ is acylindrically hyperbolic if there exists a (not necessarily finite) generating set $S\subset G$ such that $|Cay(G,S)|$ is hyperbolic, the left translation action of $G$ on $|Cay(G,S)|$ is acylindrical and $|\partial Cay(G,S)|$ contains more than two points.

